# Redirect if certain query term in WordPress Search

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress website and I want to redirect users if they search a specific term using the WordPress search functionality.

If users types "mouse" in the search box, WordPress will open this page:

```
example.com/?s=mouse
```

and **only if the query term is "mouse"**, I want to redirect the user to:

```
example2.com/bad.htm
```

If the query term is another word (e.g. cat), just use the default behaviour (show the search results).

I've tried a default redirect using .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /?s=mouse http://www.example2.com/bad.htm
```

But I still see `/?s=mouse` page and I'm not redirected.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(s=mouse|s=mouse\+dog)$
RewriteRule ^ http://example2.com/bad.htm? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @starkeen How would you edit it if I wanted to use 2 alternative terms: Redirect to example.com/bad.htm if query term is "mouse" OR "mouse+dog"

Comment: In that case, you can simply change the condition pattern to **^s=(mouse|mouse\+dog)$**